# Problems with finding implementations of methods in Yii application with PhpStorm 8

Tags: php, yii, phpstorm

I'm developing an application with Yii 1.1 using the "PHPStorm" IDE (version 8.0.2). While it manages to find declarations of  base Yii methods, it can't find implementations of methods declared in models of the application.

When I try to click on a function and choose "Go To... Implementations" in the context menu, they can not be discovered.

One of the examples:

I rightclick on a method implementation in a view and choose "go to the declaration". The IDE manages to correctly direct me to the method declaration in a model. At the same time, when I try to find implementations of the exact same method, the IDE fails to find them.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using NetBeans and as far as I know the Go to declaration depends on two things 1) to have added the framework files to project includes in case the files are outside 2) go to declaration will work based on the way you define the variables, and some of them might not work at all in case of magical methods.

But you could always declare the class of a variable by using some comments, for example:

```
$post=Post::model()->find();
$post->save();
```

If I click on `save()` might not work depending on what ::model() and find() return. But I could declare $post as Post with a comment:

```
/* @var $post Post */
```

That will let the IDE know that `$post` is of type `Post`. Then based on that it will know that it extends `CActiveRecord` and so it will locate the `save()` method and go to declaration will work.

Always make sure that either:

- functions return a instanciated object, ej: `$post=Post;`
- if not, at least specify in `@return` comment what type of object they return
- and lastly if none of them, you can always use the commenting way above

Comment: It's a good practice to comment your functions the way you did, but no one should have to change their code to satisfy limitations in the IDE.

Comment: Yes crafter but as far as I know a IDE bases the code completion and "go to declaration" depending on the codebase of the project, and most times it succeeds but sometimes the project code is so "complex" that simply cannot do it, for example, methods of a php object that are attached or loaded dynamically. For example in Yii framework there are behavior classes that can be attached to other clases to be able to extend two classes at the same time. In that case class A will have method from behaviour B, but if you do $a->methodOfB() and you go to declaration it won't work.